# Check for duplicate values within 2 linked arrays

Tags: php, loops, key

This is kind of hard to explain so please accept my bad wording of a title!

So I have two arrays. Lets call them $arrayA and $arrayB.

These arrays are [key, value] arrays. The keys are just indexes, so they just count up from 0. Both $arrayA and $arrayB relate to each other because the values in both arrays at key [i] are related. I loop through the arrays like this:

```
foreach ($arrayA as $key => $value) {
    $valueA = $value;
    $valueB = $arrayB[$key];
    doSomething($valueA, $valueB);
}
```

Now, the problem. I need to make sure im not calling the doSomething() method with duplicate combinations. For example, I should be able to do the follow calls (as I iterate through the loop and doSomething is called multiple times):

```
doSomething(1, 5);
doSomething(1, 6);
doSomething(2, 5);
```

However I shouldn't be able to do the following:

```
doSomething(1, 5);
doSomething(1, 5); // Duplicate! Stop!
```

How would I check for this throughout the iterations? I've thought I could store the values in a buffer/temporary array outside of the loop and then check that I haven't already called doSomething() with this combination before. But I have a feeling there is a more optimal way to do it within the loop. What would be my best route to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short solution:

```
$processed = array();

foreach( $arrayA as $key => $value )
{
    $valueA = $value;
    $valueB = $arrayB[$key];

    if( in_array( "$valueA,$valueB", $processed ) ) continue;
    doSomething( $valueA, $valueB );
    $processed[] = "$valueA,$valueB";
}
```

By this way, if a values couple is already processed, it is skipped.
Otherwise, if you want stop execution,  replace `continue` with `break`.

Obviously, this approach works only if you can use a character that is not in values (in this example, a comma). Otherwise, you have to use double `array_search()`: if keys matches, you can skip/stop execution.

Comment: Appreciate the response, I'm just heading home now but will test it out tomorrow and let you know how it goes! Thanks. I will edit this/add new comment at the time for an informative response rather than this.